# Laravel whereNotIn not querying as expected

Tags: php, laravel

I have a scoped query in my user class like so (`User.php`):

```
public function scopeDeleteUsersWithId($query, $userIds)
{
    return $query->whereNotIn('id', $userIds)->toSql();
}
```

I get my `$userIds` from a collection which returns an array of `id`'s. Here is my collection method (`ImportUsers.php`):

```
private function getUsersToDelete()
{
    return $this->employeeList->pluck('id')->unique()->flatten()->toArray();
}
```

And here is where I call the `getUsersToDelete` method in order to get the users to delete (`ImportUsers.php`).

```
private function deleteTerminatedEmployees()
{
    $usersToDelete = $this->getUsersToDelete();

    dd(User::deleteUsersWithId($usersToDelete));
}
```

As you can see, I am dumping the SQL so that I can see the query since it is not working. When I dump the query, I get this:

[image: raw query]

However, when I `dd($userIds)` the line before the `toSql()`, like so (`User.php`):

```
public function scopeDeleteUsersWithId($query, $userIds)
{
    dd($userIds);
    // return $query->whereNotIn('id', $userIds)->toSql();
}
```

I get the array that I am looking for:

[image]

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and cannot. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question marks are part of a prepared query. If you turn on the general log in mysql, you can see the Prepare statement like this, then the Execute statement with user ids in place of the question marks. If you're having an issue, this would not be it.

Comment: @dericcain you cannot see the query output as the above methods are using `prepared statement` which works with `bind_param` for preventing `sql injection`. I hope you understand what i mean to say.

Comment: @Manish Thanks for the heads up. So, how can I go about troubleshooting this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `DB::listen` for this.Here is the documentation [DB::listen](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database)

```
DB::listen(function ($query) {
            var_dump($query->sql); 
            var_dump($query->bindings); 
            var_dump($query->time); 
});
```

You can also find details at [scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-queries-in-laravel)

I hope this may help you.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful.